# How can I group 5 sub-queries counting total based on the value in one field in child table into one update

Tags: stored-procedures, optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

I've inherited a solution where a Stored Procedure is triggered as a post process to calculate the total number of each type of communique in the child table and update the Parent table.

The query is not optimal resulting in timeouts if the number of Child rows to the parent are more than 2-3000.

It feels as if this could be solved by grouping each of the communication types in one query instead of 5 different ones.

I'm thinking something like this pseudo code:

```
UPDATE Parent SET Total = query.Total, email = query.email, letter = query.letter, spoken = query.spoken, written = query.written
JOIN ... as query
WHERE Parent.ParentID = @pid
```

Is my gut feeling correct or are SQL Server able to optimize this internally?

Adding an index might be an option, but each of the sub queries are as far as I can see hitting one.

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateParentTotal]
 @pid int
AS
UPDATE Parent
    -- count Total
set Total = (select count(*) from Child
               where Child.ParentID = Parent.ParentID),
    -- count Type "email" total
    email  = (select count(*) from Child
               where Child.ParentID = Parent.ParentID and Type = 1),
    -- count Type "letter" total
    letter   = (select count(*) from Child
               where Child.ParentID = Parent.ParentID and Type = 2),
    -- count Total for Spoken word
    spoken = (select count(*) from Child
               where Child.ParentID = Parent.ParentID and Type > 99),
    -- count all types of written word
    written = (select count(*) from Child
               where Child.ParentID = Parent.ParentID and ((Type > 1 and Type < 100) or Type is null))
where ParentID = @pid

GO
```

PS. Naming the question was really hard, since I don't know exactly what kind of solution I need.

Comment: How/When are you calling this procedure? As this would need to be run after any change to the Child table to ensure the values in Parent aren't stale, the logical solution would be for this to be run inside a trigger on `Child`, if this is the case then the fact that you need to iterate the inserted rows and execute the procedure once for each `pid` will be more of a problem than the delay caused by the subqueries.

Comment: The workflow is as follows: A Parent contains a collection of Children. It has to be created before the Children are imported, so that the children can be grouped to it. After the import is done, the Stored procedure updating the Parent is called. A Parent will only be updated once after all the children for it has been imported. Think of the Parent as an envelope containing the children. The stored procedure is just writing on the outside of the envelope what it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in how you are thinking ... you can put all of these calculations into a single query, then connect to that.  See below for an example.

```
UPDATE Parent
SET 
    Total = CountTotal,
    Email = CountEmail
    Letter = CountLetter
    Spoken = CountSpoken
    Written = CountWritten
FROM 
    Parent 
     INNER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            ParentID,
            COUNT(*) CountTotal,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 1 THEN 1 END) AS CountEmail,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 2 THEN 1 END) AS CountLetter,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] >99 THEN 1 END) AS CountSpoken,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN (([Type] > 1 and [Type] < 100) or [Type] is null)) THEN 1 END) AS CountWritten,
        FROM Child
        GROUP BY ParentID
      ) Child ON 
        Parent.ParentID = Child.ParentID
WHERE Parent.ParentID = @pid
```

Comment: There will only be one parent record for a collection of children. So as far as I can see, you would have to use the ParentID as the condition for what will be updated.

Comment: I'll edit to remove that part - yes, based on the comments you added after I posted this originally, ParentID is absolutely required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional count to summarise your child table by parentID, e.g.

```
SELECT  ParentID,
        Email = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 1 THEN 1 END),
        Letter = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 2 THEN 1 END),
        Spoken = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] > 99 THEN 1 END),
        Written = COUNT(CASE WHEN ([Type] = > 1 AND [Type] < 100) OR [Type] IS NULL THEN 1 END),
        Total = COUNT(*)
FROM    Child
GROUP BY ParentID
```

Then it is just a case of incorporating this into your update statement:

```
WITH ChildSummary AS
(   SELECT  ParentID,
            Email = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 1 THEN 1 END),
            Letter = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 2 THEN 1 END),
            Spoken = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] > 99 THEN 1 END),
            Written = COUNT(CASE WHEN ([Type] = > 1 AND [Type] < 100) OR [Type] IS NULL THEN 1 END),
            Total = COUNT(*)
    FROM    Child
    GROUP BY ParentID
)
UPDATE  P
SET     Total = ISNULL(cs.Total, 0),
        Email = ISNULL(cs.Email, 0),
        Letter = ISNULL(cs.Letter, 0),
        Spoken = ISNULL(cs.Spoken, 0),
        Written = ISNULL(cs.Written, 0)
FROM    Parent AS p
        LEFT JOIN ChildSummary AS cs
            ON cs.ParentID = p.ParentID
WHERE   p.ParentID = @Pid;
```